# Do you really need yeast/mash nutrients?

Tags: yeast, sugar, yeast-nutrient, nutrition

This is for a sugar wash only. I have watched a video on YouTube where they only used water, sugar and turbo yeast, no nutrients were used according to the video. Whereas other guides tell you that you must use nutrients ranging from tomato paste to brewing nutrients. So which is it?

Answer (score 3):

I can't reach the website from here, but when I search for "does turbo yeast need nutrients" I get a reference stating:

> Each Turbo Yeast contains a mix of yeast and nutrients, to make 25 L of Wash

which would imply that this is tuned to the purpose and that you do not need to add any further nutrients.